# Search for all files in project containing the text 'querystring' in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I work in Dreamweaver and Eclipse when developing. I think Dreamweaver has a really nice search where you can search for text within all files of your current project.

This is handy when you want to remove a function that is called in a lot of files. You can just search within the current local project. You can choose whether to search within text or in the source code.

Does Eclipse have such a feature to find all files that have the word 'querystring' in them?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Yes, you can do this quite easily. Click on your project in the project explorer or Navigator, go to the Search menu at the top, click File..., input your search string, and make sure that 'Selected Resources' or 'Enclosing Projects' is selected, then hit search. The alternative way to open the window is with Ctrl-H. This may depend on your keyboard accelerator configuration.

More details: http://www.ehow.com/how_4742705_file-eclipse.html and http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [avajava.com](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse-02.gif))</sub>

Comment: You can also use Ctrl + h to get to the search window.

Answer (score 59):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> . Then choose "File Search" tab.

additional search options

search for resources: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

search for Java types: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Ctrl+shift+L opens the Quick text search window

Comment: Note that this requires installing STS Quick search plugin

Answer (score 5):

Just noticed that quick search has been included into eclipse 4.13 as a built-in function by typing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L (or Cmd+Alt+Shift+L on Mac)

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#quick-text-search