# troubling with find and replace function in files

Tags: php, eclipse, dreamweaver, code-editor

I know that it is not a programming question ?

But i need a another help relating to find and replace function in php code editor. I am using eclipse and Dreamweaver and i have about 650 php files and would like to replace a string in all files without opening individual files. Could you guys Please help me that, is available any function in eclipse or Dreamweaver so that i can replace the string with specified string to all files ?

There is also sub folders hierarchy.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to the *Search* menu, choose *File...*, enter the string to search and `*.php` in the file name pattern, then click the *Replace...* button.

You may also click the *Search* button, and then right-click in the Search view and choose *Replace All...* or *Replace selected...*

Comment: What are you searching for and what does it find that shouldn't be found? Have you unchecked the "regular expression" checkbox?

Comment: I have done as you suggest but it not searching the whole word. Its searching all words that are partially matched. And i have not seen any option for whole word search ? But case sensitive option is available.

Comment: What are you searching for and what does it find that shouldn't be found?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3947/discussion-between-j-j-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: i am searching "hostname" and replacing with "sunlinux"

Answer (score 0):

Googled it and, voila:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html

Step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In Dreamweaver, CTRL+F (or *Edit* > *Find* (*and replace*)) then choose whatever you want from "Find in:" dropdown menu. You have:

- *Selected Text*
- *Current Document*
- *Open Documents*
- *Folder...*
- *Selected Files in Site*
- *Entire Current Local Site*

For eclipse, check this: [Search for all files in project containing the text 'querystring' in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602114/search-for-all-files-in-project-containing-the-text-querystring-in-eclipse)