# Searching a string in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse

How to search for a string in the complete eclipse workspace?
I was not able to locate a text in the eclipse workspace however I could not find the specified string in  the workspace.

Comment: In addition to Francis Upton's answer, check for any extra spaces at the end of your string. It happens sometimes.

Comment: The search is not efficient enough.Though there is an occurence of the string it does not find it.It says File search has encountered a problem.

Comment: You need to refresh the files in your workspace, in the Project/Package Explorer, right click and select "Refresh" at any level (project, folder, file). This will sync your workspace with the underlying file system and prevent the problem.

Comment: Upvoted because I had the same question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602114/search-for-all-files-in-project-containing-the-text-querystring-in-eclipse

Answer (score 116, accepted):

At the top level menus, select **'Search' -> 'File Search'** Then near the bottom (in the scope) there is a choice to select the **entire workspace**.

For your **"File search has encountered a problem"**, you need to refresh the files in your workspace, in the Project/Package Explorer, right click and select "**Refresh**" at any level (project, folder, file). This will sync your workspace with the underlying file system and prevent the problem.

Comment: +1 for explaining the cryptic 'file search has encountered a problem'

Answer (score 47):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, should bring up the search that will include options to search via project, directory, etc.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> can be used to find selected text across a workspace in eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl+ H, Select "File Search", indicate the "file name pattern", for example *.xml or *.java. And then select the scope "Workspace"

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse does not search if the "File name patterns" field is **empty**.
So, if you want to search some text, write within "Containing text" field
and leave 
by default "File name patterns" with asterisk (*).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers only explain how to do the search.

To view the results look for a search tab (normally docked at the bottom of the screen):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[eclipse instasearch plugin](https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch) is a very useful plugin for search needs inside eclipse.
It is based on lucene. This is also available in eclipse marketplace.

It has extensive feature set.

- Instantly shows search results
- Shows a preview using relevant lines
- Periodically updates the index
- Matches partial words (e.g. case in CamelCase)
- Opens and highlights matches in files
- Searches JAR source attachments
- Supports filtering by extension/project/working set

Answer (score 2):

**For Mac:**

**Quick Text Search:** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[image]

**All other search** (like File Search, Git Search, Java Search etc): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Goto Search->File

You will get an window, you can give either simple search text or regx pattern. Once you enter your search keyword click Search and make sure that Scope is Workspace.

You may use this for Replace as well.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+shift+L` and type your string

Comment: This hotkey for strings search available in eclipse if spring quicksearch installed

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse editor screen, try <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> buttons.