# How to search eclipse for a particular statement or line of text

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to replace a library import from my Java classes in `src/main/java` and in `src/test/java` how can I search to find which classes use the old library from eclipse?

Example:

I want to search all classes across all my projects which contain the following string:

> import de.oio.jpdfunit*

the " * " is wildcard character
so I can replace it with:

> import de.ga.pdfGenerator

I tried cmd+shift+t and that doesn't help,

Comment: You can use the search tool in eclipse try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602114/search-for-all-files-in-project-containing-the-text-querystring-in-eclipse).

Comment: I use [Ctrl + H] hotkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using File Search which can find even string texts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this helped, please accept it as the right answer :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it wouldn't let me accept the answer until after 5 minutes J