# Azure web app throwing error when referring to non-existent path

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a reason why my web app inside an Azure web app is returning a *404* error saying:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> > The path for the file is: *https://WEB-APP-NAME-HERE.azurewebsites.net/resources/demos/style.css*

If I look into my project files and folders, I do not have a *recources* folder, nor a *demos* folder and for sure no *style.css* file.

Can this message be turned of inside **portal.azure.net**? Or can this path be deleted so that Azure / the web app doesn't check it anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my problem. I found it (see below). The _URL_ wouldn't be off any help, it is blocked by our **Active Directory** logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched your actual code for a reference to that file?

Or would it previously have been there and a bot is trying to re-read it?

Comment: I feel dumb :). Thanks for the solution. JQuery DataPicker was trying to load that link. I removed the link and now the error is gone. The DataPickers are still working after the removal of said link. [I used this SO post to search for the string in the entire project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602114/search-for-all-files-in-project-containing-the-text-querystring-in-eclipse)